# Change object properties within a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uibutton

Is there any reason why I'm unable to change properties of an object within a cell? I have a couple of buttons within a cell, and when one is selected, the other cell should be unselected. This works fine, unless I set the property when setting up the cell. For example I set up outlets in my header:

```
@interface FlipsideViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIActionSheetDelegate> {

    UIButton *mButton;
    UIButton *fButton;

}
```

Then `@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *mButton;` them, and synthesise. If I toggle the selected status using `mButton.selected = YES;` that works fine, but if I setup a default value (i.e. set one of the buttons to selected) as the cell is being created, it refuses to let me toggle selected state. It always stays selected.

I tried using UIImageViews too, toggling their alpha property using a button, but if I set up the alpha property during cell creation it will never change from that state.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    // ... some text label stuff deleted here.

    cell.opaque = NO;

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;

}

if (indexPath.row == 2) {
    // Gender
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Gender";
    UIImageView *tmpImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"UICellsBottom.png"]];
    cell.backgroundView = tmpImage;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    // Male button
    mButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
    mButton.frame = CGRectMake(200, 3, 45, 45);
    mButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
    [mButton setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"MF-Male-Off@2x.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [mButton setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"MF-Male-On@2x.png"] forState: UIControlStateSelected];
    [mButton addTarget:self action:@selector(male) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell addSubview: mButton];

    mButton.selected = YES;

    // Female button
    fButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
    fButton.frame = CGRectMake(254, 3, 45, 45);
    fButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
    [fButton setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"MF-Female-Off@2x.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [fButton setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"MF-Female-On@2x.png"] forState: UIControlStateSelected];
    [fButton addTarget:self action:@selector(female) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell addSubview: fButton];

}

return cell;
}
```

And then my buttons actions are like follows:

```
- (void) male
{
    gender = @"m";
    mButton.selected = YES;
    fButton.selected = NO;
}
```

Comment: It seems you create your buttons without the Interface Builder, so why not remove the IBOutlet from your _@property_? Just a suggestion. ;)

Comment: oooooooh so thats what IBOutlet means!

Comment: Oh yeah, IB(Interface Builder)Outlet~ ;)

Comment: I guess thats also why I haven't had any errors setting my button methods to `- (void)` rather than `- (IBAction)`.. I learned something today :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
 mButton.selected = YES;
```

use

```
[mButton setHighlighted:YES];
```

Comment: Worked perfectly once I set the highlight state.